# How can I mock a class using jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

How can I mock something to test something like the following codes. I tried to follow this official doc, but still not working for me https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter

// somefile.ts

```
export const myPublish = async (event: any, context: any): Promise<any> => {
  const myExportHelper = await ExportHelper.getInstance({
    ...commonProps,
  });

  // just some other stuff
  // just some other stuff

  await myExportHelper.transfer(arg1, arg2);
};

export class ExportHelper {
  constructor(
    private readonly bucket: string,
    private readonly read: AWS.S3,
    private readonly write: AWS.S3
  ) {}

  static async getInstance(props: {
    param1: string;
  }) {
    ...
    ...

    return new ExportHelper(arg1, arg2, arg3);
  };

  async transfer(param1, param2) {
    ...
    ...
    console.log('bla bla bla');
  }
}
```

// testfile.test.ts

```
import { myPublish, ExportHelper } from '../somefile';

beforeEach(() => {
});

afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
});

describe('myTest', () => {
    it('should run successfully', async () => {
        // Arrange
        const eventMock = {
            Records: [
                {
                    ...
                }
            ]
        }

        jest.mock('../somefile');
        const mockActualExportHelper = jest.requireActual('../somefile').ExportHelper;
        
        const mockGetInstanceImpl = () => {};

        // this says cannot read property instances of undefined
        const mockExportHelper = mockActualExportHelper.mock.instances[0]; 
        mockExportHelper.getInstance.mockImplementation(mockGetInstanceImpl);
        mockExportHelper.transfer.mockImplementation(mockGetInstanceImpl);

        // Act
        await myPublish(eventMock, jasmine.any({}));

        // Assert
        expect(ExportHelper.getInstance).toBeCalled();
        expect(ExportHelper.transfer).toBeCalled(); // also not sure if this is valid to use ExportHelper
        
    });
});
```

Comment: What's `myPublish`? Show the code.

Comment: @slideshowp2 it really does not matter, you can even treat it as arg1 = "test", arg2 = "test" if you want to

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, mocking partially, reading from `.mock` on something which was a class, referencing to "mock with factory function" while you don't use that form - does not help to get the idea. Normally we either mock whole file, or consume file as is and mock its external dependencies(in your case it would be `AWS`), trying to mock partially rarely reaches good results.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is not a mock. If you want to *spy* what functions are called, you will need to use the `spyOn`. In jest you can do the following:

```
jest.spyOn(MyClass, 'myMethod');
```

And you can also `mock` the implementation to subtitute the default behavior of a method, a generalist example can be like this:

```
jest.spyOn(MyClass, 'myMethod').mockImplementation(jest.fn());
```

---

With that said, I would rewrite the test to spy the methods from `ExportHelper` and avoid external calls:

```
import {ExportHelper, myPublish} from '../app';

beforeEach(() => {
});

afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
});

describe('myTest', () => {
    it('should run successfully', async () => {
        // Arrange
        const eventMock = {
            Records: [
                {
                    // ...
                }
            ]
        }


        jest.spyOn(ExportHelper, 'getInstance').mockImplementation(jest.fn());
        jest.spyOn(ExportHelper, 'transfer').mockImplementation(jest.fn());

        // Act
        await myPublish('arg1', 'arg2');

        // Assert
        expect(ExportHelper.getInstance).toBeCalled();
        expect(ExportHelper.transfer).toBeCalled();
    });
});
```

I just replaced this piece of code:

```
        jest.mock('../somefile');
        const mockActualExportHelper = jest.requireActual('../somefile').ExportHelper;
        
        const mockGetInstanceImpl = () => {};

        // this says cannot read property instances of undefined
        const mockExportHelper = mockActualExportHelper.mock.instances[0]; 
        mockExportHelper.getInstance.mockImplementation(mockGetInstanceImpl);
        mockExportHelper.transfer.mockImplementation(mockGetInstanceImpl);
```

with

```
        jest.spyOn(ExportHelper, 'getInstance').mockImplementation(jest.fn());
        jest.spyOn(ExportHelper, 'transfer').mockImplementation(jest.fn());
```

Because jest will track down and watch any of these method's calls and then we can use jest's matchers to test if both of them were called. And the `mockImplementation` will isolate any further calls to be maded.

---

One thing that I noticed while reproducing your example, is that the `transfer` method is not being treated as a method when you get the instance from `getInstance` and therefore, the tests will not pass. But I think this question is not in the scope of the topic. Dunno if just happens to me.